# Java NIO2: Need clarification on FileChannel

Tags: java, filechannel, nio2

I'm trying to build a custom [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), and I'm experiencing a lack of clarity due to inconsistency in the documentation.

The documentation for the [`FileChannel.transferFrom(ReadableByteChannel src, long position, long count)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29) method says,

> If the given position is greater than the file's current size then no bytes are transferred.

Now, shouldn't they have said this **instead**? :

> "If `position + count` is greater than file's current size then no bytes are transferred."

The reason I **suspect** this may be a bug in the documentation is this. Elsewhere in the same API doc, if the file needs to grow, an explicit mention of it is made, as in the case of [`FileChannel.write(ByteBuffer src, long position)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#write%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long%29):

> "If the given position is greater than the file's current size then the file will be grown to accommodate the new bytes;"

So, if no mention has been made of any file growth in case of [`FileChannel.transferFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29), I get the impression that file is not supposed to grow via this method. But **the problem is**, the file can grow not only *"If the given position is greater than the file's current size"* but also "if `position + count` is greater than file's current size".

Answer (score 0):

Same [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom%28java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long%29) as you:

> Fewer than the requested number of bytes will be transferred if the source channel has fewer than count bytes remaining, or if the source channel is non-blocking and has fewer than count bytes immediately available in its input buffer.

<s>And why should transferFrom grow the ReadableBiteChannel?</s>

So: **No**

### Edit 1:

> "If position + count is greater than file's current size then no bytes are transferred."

means that:

```
Path sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/FileChannelDemo/source.txt");
Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:/FileChannelDemo/target.txt");

Files.createDirectories(sourcePath.getParent());

BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(sourcePath,
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// 200k
while (Files.size(sourcePath) < 200 * 1024)
    writer.write(System.currentTimeMillis() + "\n");

FileChannel src = FileChannel.open(sourcePath, StandardOpenOption.READ);

FileChannel trgt = FileChannel.open(targetPath, EnumSet.of(StandardOpenOption.WRITE, 
        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING));

int count = 200*1024;

System.out.println("current size is: " + Files.size(targetPath) + "smaller than  count:" +count);

trgt.transferFrom(src, 0, count);
```

wouldn't transfer any data. *But it does.*

Reasons not to transfer `count`bytes are stated above.

Comment: My question is about the destination `FileChannel` on which `transferFrom` is being invoked... where the bytes from the source will go. I'm not seeking clarifications on the source channel.